# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after n

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

So I'm trying to parse a JSONObject but I keep getting the error:

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after n at character 5 of {n  "24h_avg": 334.22,n  "ask": 335.96,n  "bid": 335.7,n  "last": 335.84,n  "timestamp": "Tue, 23 Dec 2014 22:13:55 -0000",n  "volume_btc": 30328.82,n  "volume_percent": 82.62n}n`

I'm able to get the json I need from the server but it's not being parsed right for some odd reason.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String URL = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD/";
TextView mPriceText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        JSONParse parse = new JSONParse();
        parse.execute();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }

    return isAvailable;
}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting price ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJsonFromUrl(URL);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // jokes = json.getJSONArray(TAG_JOKE);
            // getting json from url
            //JSONObject c = json.getJ();
            // store json item
            String price = (String) json.get("24h_avg");
            // set json data in textview
            mPriceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
            mPriceText.setText(price);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my JSON Parser class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject getJsonFromUrl(String url) {

    // Make request
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        // try parsing the string to a JSON object
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return json string
    return jObj;
}
```

And lastly, here is the json that I'm trying to parse.

```
{
  "24h_avg": 333.8,
  "ask": 337.79,
  "bid": 337.31,
  "last": 337.77,
  "timestamp": "Tue, 23 Dec 2014 20:06:17 -0000",
  "volume_btc": 29261.88,
  "volume_percent": 81.98
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the error message notice the strange "n" characters:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after n at character 5 of {n  "24h_avg": 334.22,n  "ask": 335.96,n  "bid": 335.7,n  "last": 335.84,n  "timestamp": "Tue, 23 Dec 2014 22:13:55 -0000",n  "volume_btc": 30328.82,n  "volume_percent": 82.62n}n

It's because you append an "n" at the end of each line here:

> ```
>     while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
>         sb.append(line + "n");
>     }
> ```

Change to a newline character "\n":

```
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in the line reading loop. Replace `sb.append(line + "n");` with `sb.append(line + "\n");`

If you want to avoid the extra invisible StringBuilder allocation happening in `line + "\n"` you should do `sb.append(line).append("\n");`